# Signalr broadcast from web api

Tags: signalr

What is the best practice to SignalR broadcast from webapi which is located in another project to mvc application when you install signalr package in the mvc application?

- MVC - localhost:8080
- API - localhost:8080/api (lives in a different project)
- Hubs - Shared class library for Hubs

The problem is, if i install signalr package in MVC application, it doesnt work, but if i install it in API application, it then works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need hubs to be shared, hubs are necessary (if you use the Hubs API) only to the broadcaster. You can remove their usage from the MVC project.

Moreover, you do not need the full SignalR package in both. The WebAPI will hardly have its own JS clients (they come from the MVC one), so it is enough to install just the SignalR **.NET** client library. Same reasoning on the MVC project, that is just a client from a SignalR perspective, so you just need to install the SignalR **JS** package. I'm assuming you are broadcasting from WebAPI project directly towards the MVC users in their browsers, however if you are trying to achieve a server-to-server broadcasting then you'll need the .NET client library there too, but still no need to share hubs.

Comment: Hub class is in a shared project because from different projects i can call the connection using GlobalHost class.

var signalRConnectionId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub"];
            GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>()
                .Clients
                .Client(signalRConnectionId)
                .sendMessage('test');

Comment: That's fine, from your question I was not sure you knew they were not needed specifically for the problem you describe.